# WAR file with symlinks

Tags: java, tomcat, war, symlink

I have WAR file that contains symlinks for certain libraries.

When I extract the war file into webapps folder using unzip command it creates the symlink properly and web app loads without any issues.

However when I place the WAR file in webapps and let Tomcat deploy it , the symlink becomes a simple text file.

How do I overcome this situation, is there a way to customize the WAR explosion process.

### EDIT

I suspect this is because Tomcat user Jar command to unpack a war file, is there a way to make tomcat use unzip command instead?

Comment: maybe the tomcat user doesn't have permissions permissions?

Comment: Creation of war deploy happened as the same user and user has owner permission...

Comment: seems hacky, but maybe call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` and make ur symlink that way.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Yes that is one of the idea I have however I can execute this only in a startup servlet or `ServletContextListener`. I have to restart the server after the symlinks are created, isn't it?